# How do I setup Dispatcher InvokeAsync Method using moq

Tags: c#, wpf, nunit, moq, dispatcher

I'm new to unit testing and trying to Mock Dispatcher by writing a wrapper method, but I'm unable to setup the `InvokeAsync` method to callback.

IDispatcher:

```
public interface IDispatcher
    {
        // other implementations

        DispatcherOperation InvokeAsync(Action action);

        DispatcherOperation<TResult> InvokeAsync<TResult>(Func<TResult> callback);
    }
```

DispatcherWrapper:

```
public class DispatcherWrapper : IDispatcher
{
        // Other implementations
        public DispatcherOperation InvokeAsync(Action action)
        {
            return this.UIDispatcher.InvokeAsync(action);
        }

        public DispatcherOperation<TResult> InvokeAsync<TResult>(Func<TResult> callback)
        {
            return this.UIDispatcher.InvokeAsync(callback);
        }
}
```

The way I'm trying to set it up:

```
// this works as expected
this.mockDispatcher.Setup(x => x.BeginInvoke(It.IsAny<Action>())).Callback((Action a) => a());
```

```
// get an exception : System.ArgumentException : Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters (Func<Action>) cannot invoke callback with parameters (Action).
this.mockDispatcher.Setup(x => x.InvokeAsync(It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType>>())).Callback((Action a) => a());
```

Usage:

```
var res = await this.dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
                                             {
                                                // returns a result by computing some logic
                                             });
```

I'm facing the issue only with the test project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-generic version accepts an `Action` parameter:

```
mockDispatcher.Setup(x => x.InvokeAsync(It.IsAny<Action>())).Callback((Action a) => a());
```

The generic version accepts a `Func<TResult>`:

```
mockDispatcher.Setup(x => x.InvokeAsync(It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType>>())).Callback(() => /* ... */ });
```

If you want to invoke the `Func<TResult>` in the callback, you should either specify the type argument or capture the `Func<TResult>`:

```
Func<int> someFunc = () => 10;
mockDispatcher.Setup(x => x.InvokeAsync(It.IsAny<Func<It.IsAnyType>>())).Callback(() => someFunc());
```

Comment: I do need to use the generic version with a generic return type without creating `someFunc` method is it possible??  can I make something like this to work?, `this.mockDispatcher.Setup(x => x.InvokeAsync<string>(It.IsAny<Func<string>>())).Callback((Func<string> callback) => callback.Invoke());`

Comment: Nevermind all I was missing was `List<string>` and it worked with `this.mockDispatcher.Setup(x => x.InvokeAsync(It.IsAny<Func<List<string>>>())).Callback((Func<List<string>> callback) => callback.Invoke());`